# How Do I Empty a Subtree in a Binary Tree in C?

Tags: c, tree, binary-tree, subtree

Currently when I call this function, it deletes all child nodes and frees the memory of the node I passed it, but the node is still linked to it's parent and contains garbage.
I need to be able to set the parent node of the node I passed (either left or right child) equal to `NULL` so the program doesn't crash when traversing the tree.

Here is the code I already have:

```c
void emptySubtree(BinaryNode* node) {
    if (node == NULL)
        return;

    emptySubtree(node->left);
    emptySubtree(node->right);
    free(node);
}
```

Here is my function call: `emptySubtree(tree->root->left)`

Comment: Pass the pointer by address and set it to `NULL` after freeing it. A bit overkill if you ask me though, since you just passed that pointer to `emptySubstree`, what is stopping you from `tree->root->left = NULL;` afterward ?

Comment: The snippet that you posted, actually is suppose to delete all the nodes for the passed `node` including itself, since deletion is being made in post traversal order. Before calling this function and passing it the node, simply set the `parent->left = NULL` for `if (parent->data > node)` else do the opposite.

Answer (score 1):

```
void emptySubtree(BinaryNode* node){
    if (node == NULL)
       return;
    else{
        emptySubtree(node->left);
        emptySubtree(node->right);
    }
    free(node);
    node = NULL;
}
```

Try setting the pointer node to null. Good practice after you call free.

Comment: Think about what will happen if this node has no children and only contains one element. Will this function successfully set it to point to null?

Comment: What's the point of setting `node = NULL;` at the end of the function?  Node is a local variable, so the statement is useless.

Comment: @Smac89 - I believe it will.  Follow it through and see (Although much depends on the contents of the BinaryNode type)

Comment: @JS1 node may be local, but its a pointer.  This points to whatever object was used as the function parameter. Setting a pointer to NULL is not useless (in the correct context of course)

Comment: @Grantly I do not think that code means what you think it means.  (Said in my best Inigo Montoya accent).  Your code is equivalent to OP's code.  It won't NULL out the pointer passed in, as the pointer was passed in by value not by reference.  If you don't believe me, compile it and find out.

Comment: @JS1 Gotcha :) Thanks for the correction.  I wasn't considering the pointer to pointer of BinaryNode.

Answer (score 1):

```
void emptySubtree(BinaryNode **pNode)
{
    BinaryNode *node = *pNode;

    if (node == NULL)
        return;

    emptySubtree(&node->left);
    emptySubtree(&node->right);
    free(node);
    *pNode = NULL;
}
```

Call with `emptySubtree(&tree->root->left);`

Or even more simple:

```
// This is your function, renamed.
void emptySubtreeHelper(BinaryNode* node) {
    if (node == NULL)
        return;

    emptySubtreeHelper(node->left);
    emptySubtreeHelper(node->right);
    free(node);
}

void emptySubtree(BinaryNode **pNode) {
    emptySubtreeHelper(*pNode);
    *pNode = NULL;
}
```

Again, call with `emptySubtree(&tree->root->left);`